# Can't verify JWT

Tags: python, jwt, apple-search-ads

I am trying to create a JWT token for apple search ads like in this example :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_search_ads/implementing_oauth_for_the_apple_search_ads_api

I generated my private key like this:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -noout -out private-key.pem
```

and public key like this:

```
openssl ec -in private-key.pem -pubout -out public-key.pem
```

then I did like this :

```
import jwt
import datetime as dt

client_id = "SEARCHADS.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
team_id = "SEARCHADS.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
key_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
audience = "https://appleid.apple.com"
alg = "ES256"

# Define issue timestamp.
issued_at_timestamp = int(dt.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
# Define expiration timestamp. May not exceed 180 days from issue timestamp.
expiration_timestamp = issued_at_timestamp + 86400 * 180

# Define JWT headers.
headers = dict()
headers["alg"] = alg
headers["kid"] = key_id

# Define JWT payload.
payload = dict()
payload["sub"] = client_id
payload["aud"] = audience
payload["iat"] = issued_at_timestamp
payload["exp"] = expiration_timestamp
payload["iss"] = team_id

# Path to signed private key.
KEY_FILE = "private-key.pem"

with open(KEY_FILE, "r") as key_file:
    key = "".join(key_file.readlines())

client_secret = jwt.encode(payload=payload, headers=headers, algorithm=alg, key=key)

with open("client_secret.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write(client_secret.decode("utf-8"))
```

SearchAds_PrivateKey.pem is like this:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The token generated has an invalid signature on jwt.io.

[image]
I found this topic: [KJUR jws jsrsasign: Cannot validate ES256 token on JWT.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71307444/kjur-jws-jsrsasign-cannot-validate-es256-token-on-jwt-io) and I tried the solution but it does not work for me

Comment: Could you please share a sample JWT you have generated

Comment: I replace client_id, team_id and key_id like in the example and the result is : eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYIn0.eyJzdWIiOiJTRUFSQ0hBRFMuWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFgiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2FwcGxlaWQuYXBwbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjUzMjkzMTY5LCJleHAiOjE2Njg4NDUxNjksImlzcyI6IlNFQVJDSEFEUy5YWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWCJ9.MEUCIH-4XHVPuiY4U1DPRS_4A35K3PBp4Lu3ehj_6HPX3TFUAiEA8QQaKa4mCyHPbSLyMF2AS8ghZ-ufxNfm63PfjS2k0zM

Comment: Please make sure that you have uploaded your public key corresponding to the private key you are signing the JWT with.

Comment: Have you correctly generated and uploaded the public key?

Comment: Yes I verified, I don't know why it does not works.

Comment: I generated it with the python script in the post, I copied and paste it from apple documentation

Comment: @luc what did you copy from apple documentation? The implementation? The question is - where did you get the public key from? It should be generated together with the private key. You can also derive a public key from the private one that you have. You then have to upload that public key to jwt.io and only then jwt.io will be able to verify the signature.

Comment: I added some information on the post, thanks for help

Comment: @luc have you tried what Michal has suggested? Are you using the correct public key to verify?

Answer (score 1):

The steps you have taken are correct. For testing jwt in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) as you see in the picture below you should fill the `Encoded` and `VERIFY SIGNATURE` sections with your JWT and your public key respectively. Then you'll see that the signature will be verified!

[image]

Comment: I tried but it does not work :(